# Translations for "Site" in the context of a location?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

Site can have many variations of a location in English but I am looking for the word in the context of a site like a work site, construction site, etc. But not looking for the translation of "location." Think of site like a worksite, that is what I am looking for.

In a specific example, lets say that I have software to schedule plumbers to visit different hotels, etc. So on their calendar app if they saw something like "Site 1 - Oceanside Hotel", "Site 2 - LAX Marriot", "Site 3 - Riverfront Hotel "

When I attempted to look this up in Google translate, I kept getting the wrong context of "websites", which is not what I want. When I searched more I found the following options

- Standort
- Stelle
- Stätte

I think Standort would fit best since it seems to be related to "location, site, position, habitat, garrison, stand".

But Stelle also seems to be in line with what I want, since it relates to "point, place, site, location, position, office".

Stätte seems to be generic and might fit?

So looking for the context of when I could use either word, and the plural version is.

So far leaning towards "Standort", but confused because it seems to be the same spelling for singular and plural forms.

Answer (score 5):

### Answering the specified question

With the concrete use-case now added to the original question, namely: a list of locations where construction workers such as plumbers etc. are being sent to to do a job for a probably short time:

> Einsatzort: [name of the hotel, address..]

would be the usual word to use.

*Einsatzort* is the place where a worker goes for a short time assignment. It can also refer to a place where police goes to check for some incident or whatever, where a fire brigade is being sent etc. But it is a good word also for shorttime tasks for construction workers. The crucial thing is that the location is not the regular, constant location for the job as in case of factory workers or office personnel.

An additional consideration might be: Depending on how this list looks like, e.g. does the word *Einsatzort* appear in every line, and how much place does it occupy there, you may find *Einsatzort* too long. In that case it is an option to use simply:

> Ort: [name of the hotel, address]

because those who read the list (the plumbers, their dispatcher, etc.) know what is being meant.

---

Here is a list of terms that are used for various types of "sites" in another context. All these terms are existing, and are in everyday use. All of them have their specific situation in life where they are appropriate (and where not), and they cannot be simply interchanged even when having the same first part.

> *Arbeitsstelle* *Arbeitsort* *Arbeitsplatz* *Einsatzort* *Einsatzplatz* *Einsatzstelle* Ort des Geschehens Unfallort Unfallstelle Unfallgelände Rummelplatz Landeplatz Landestelle Treffpunkt *Verkaufsort* Verkaufsstelle  *Standort* Standplatz Sitzplatz *Verkaufspunkt* Bauplatz *Baustelle* *Montageort* *Montageplatz* Fussballplatz Trainingsgelände Übungsplatz Tatort Zeltplatz Lagerplatz Lagerstelle *Betriebsort* *Betriebsstätte*

If you narrow it down to things that can be used for *worksite* - in the sense: a place where something work-related is happening - again it depends on what type of work you have in mind. In the list above I marked those that could fit - depending on context - with italic.

For some of the terms it is ambiguous: A *Tatort* is a crime scene. Of course, for the investigators this is the place where they do their work. A *Rummelplatz* is a fairground or amusement park, and of course some people are working there.

Comment: I think you are overcomplicating this, I gave the example of worksite or site for office. Words such as "Rummelplatz" are completely out of context.

Comment: @JGallardo  Yes, of course, Rummelplatz, Flugplatz, Landeplatz etc. are out of (your) context. They are in the list due to their being semantically or constitutents-wise close to other terms in the list. But still, your "worksite" is just not clear enough. It can mean hundreds of things where in German quite probably a more specific term would be most common. You should give a proper description of what you exactly have in mind. Also "office" is a broad term. Do you mean a venue with writing desks? Or public office in terms of a position in public administration etc.?

Answer (score 4):

The correct translation can be one of these proposals:

- Ort (a place like a village)
- Stelle (a place with limited area)
- Standort (a place with a special purpose e.g. business-center)

The roots are as follows:

- ward = war = place that has been occupied (by humans)
- stellen = to place something of interest to a limited area of ground
- Stand = something that has been erected

Concerning your purpose of using it for "work site" maybe following is more interesting for you:

- Arbeitsplatz (work-place)
- Einsatzort (temporal-occupation-place)
- Standort (in the context of a business location of a company)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Standort makes sense, what would be the plural version of that?

Comment: the plural of Standort is: Standorte (but you would need it reflexed, which this is not)

Comment: One further possible candidate is *Firmengelände*, where the (possibly enclosed) area of the site is intended.